# some questions on condtional expecatation-Is this sigma algerba, Is $X$ measurable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

[image]

[image]

**Q1** Is this $\mathscr{G}$ sigma-algebra? I don't think so because $\{a,b,c\}\notin\mathscr{G}$.

**Q2** If it is not sigma-algebra, How is that possible to condition on non-sigma algebra? Most of relevant examples using $\{\emptyset,A,A^c,\Omega\}$, however this is sigma-algebra.

**Q3** Is this $X$-$\mathscr{G}$ measurable? How can you tell?

Those questions are quite important for me to deepen my understanding of both operations and concept, genuinely thinks for your help in answering sequentially, please let me know whether **Q1** is right or wrong.

Comment: You didn't show what $X$ was to begin with. In any case this $\mathcal{G}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra so there is some problem here. Presumably what is meant is that you have the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{ \{ a,b \},\{ c\},\{ d \}\}$. This will yield that expression for the conditional expectation.

Comment: @Ian May I know what exactly the problem is, I am not sure what do you meant by what $X$ was to begin with. I've uploaded one more captures

Comment: Before the edit, we couldn't answer Q3 because we hadn't been told what $X$ is.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, your $\mathscr G$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.  The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the disjoint events $\{a,b\}$, $\{c\}$, and $\{d\}$ is
   $$\{\emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{c\}, \{d\}, \{a,b,c\}, \{a,b,d\},\{c,d\},\Omega\}$$
   That's the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{G}$ the question is asking about
2. When you write conditional expectations conditioned on an expression that isn't a $\sigma$-algebra, the usual meaning is that you want to condition on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that expression.
3. The $X$ that are measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by your $\mathscr{G}$ are the ones that are (a.s.) constant on any of the basic sets $\{a,b\}$, $\{c\}$, and $\{d\}$ that have non-zero probability. That's what the proof means by *"can be generated by indicators of the form $\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$"*

"Measurable" in this finite, discrete setting means "if you know occurrence/non-occurrence for all the events in the $\sigma$-algebra, do you know the value of $X$?".  The definition of measurability gets complicated for uncountably infinite sets, because what you mean by "know" and "all the events" gets complicated, but here it is still simple.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a bit confused your *3* combined with the above expression. I am clear that $X$ is a constant function on atoms $\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\}$ of sigma-algebra generated by $\mathscr{G}=\sigma(\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\})$. Then isn't this saying $X$- $\sigma(\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\})$ measurable? If so, Why does not $E(X|\sigma(\{a,b\},\{c\},\{d\}))=X$ but that capture equation